# Java Swing table doesn't show rows at the end and won't scroll

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

[image]

I created this table using NetBeans IDE. Problem is, if it has more than 20 rows, it only shows those 20 rows. Other rows are not showing and it won't scroll .

It shows only half of the last row in the table(see picture) .

I changed the scroll pane width and height, and I put the table in another scroll pane but this didn't work.

This code is  generated from NetBeans.

> spStockItems.setAutoscrolls(true);
>           spStockItems.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(452, 300));
>           spStockItems.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(452, 300));
>
> ```
>     tblStockItems.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 11)); // NOI18N
>     tblStockItems.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
>         new Object [][] {
>             {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
>             {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
>             {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
>             {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
>             {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
>             {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
>             {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
>             {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
>             {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
>             {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
>             {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
>             {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
>             {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
>             {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
>             {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
>             {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
>             {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
>             {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
>             {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
>             {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
>             {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
>             {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
>             {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
>             {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
>             {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
>             {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
>             {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
>             {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
>             {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null}
>         },
>         new String [] {
>             "Item Name", "Ref. No.", "Available Qty.", "Unit", "Ledger No.", "Sup ID", "Raw Price", "Item Code", "Ref. ID.", "Full
> ```
>
> Ledger No", "From to Ledger", "Full Item Code", "Unit Price", "Item
>   Type", "GRN Type", "StockID", "AnnRP", "stop", "percentage"
>               }
>           ) {
>               boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
>                   false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false,
>   false, false
>               };
>
> ```
>         public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
>             return canEdit [columnIndex];
>         }
>     });
>     tblStockItems.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(452, 300));
>     tblStockItems.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(452, 300));
>     tblStockItems.setRowHeight(14);
>     spStockItems.setViewportView(tblStockItems);
>     tblStockItems.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(250);
>     tblStockItems.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setMinWidth(0);
>     tblStockItems.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(0);
>     tblStockItems.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setMaxWidth(0);
> ```

Comment: See [How to use scrollpanes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html), you will need to add your `JTable` to a `JScrollPane` and NOT mess with the `preferred/minimum/maximumSize` of the `JTable`

Comment: How do you expect anyone here to fix broken code you do not show?  Note: code is more useful than a screenshot in this case.  For better help sooner, post an **[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example)**.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Like we do every answer, voodoo!

Comment: @MadProgrammer  I have nothing against Voodoo.  The only problem is, my supply of skulls for the rituals has disappeared.  ..Bloody conservationists!

Comment: Kill this `spStockItems.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(452, 300));`

Comment: Note to the OP:  A couple of uncompilable code snippets is not an MCVE. -1 for posting without even reading it.

Comment: Start by getting out of the form editor and start handing the UI, it will give you a better of idea of what is going on and why it's going wrong

Comment: Ok if put my enter code it getting  again a mesh. thank you you help  Andrew Thompson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of...

```
spStockItems.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(452, 300));     
spStockItems.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(452, 300));
```

And...

```
tblStockItems.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(452, 300));
tblStockItems.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(452, 300));
```

These are screwing with how the `JScrollPane` determines when your table needs to scroll.

Learn to use layout managers to your advantage and don't be afraid to use multiple layouts across multiple components to build up your UI.

Take the time to learn to hand code your UI's, it will give you a greater idea of what it is going on and the limitations of the form editor (and when to use them)

Comment: Ahaaa thank you very much it works! cheers! MadProgrammer

Comment: Glad you got it working